# What additional (probably basic) configuration do I need to do to enable CGI execution under Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm setting up a system, and I seem to be missing a basic aspect of Apache configuration. I am getting a 403 error when I attempt to load 127.0.0.1/index.cgi.

My sites-enabled conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/christos/link
    <Directory />
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/christos/link>
        Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**--UPDATE--**

When I try to access index.cgi by a browser, I get the error:

`[Sun Feb 21 08:17:22.696180 2021] [authz_core:error] [pid 357134:tid 139716048369408] [client ::1:36924] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/christos/neo-fathers/document_root/index.cgi`

Comment: Is mod_cgi enabled?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman `a2enmod cgi` gets `Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi.
Module cgid already enabled`.

Comment: It can be file permissions or apache permissions problem. Can you update the question by adding the apache error log output?

Comment: @Krackout, I checked filesystem permissions by checking directory permissions with `ls -l` and also by changing `www-data`'s shell to `/bin/bash`, suing to `www-data`, and then manually executing the script. I did not turn up a permissioning error. But let me update the question; thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your Apache version, configuration and log, you need to add `Require all granted` for each directory:

```
... (rest of conf)
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You can change `all` to something more specific if you prefer, check apache docs.